# Elegir datos aleatorios de varias listas en Python sabiendo el origen de cada dato

Tags: python, lista, random

Supongamos que tengo tres listas con datos y quiero escoger k datos aleatorios de ellas, sabiendo en cada caso de qué lista procede cada dato. Si hago esto:

```
import random as rd   

test01 = list(range(1,11))

test02 = list(range(1,11))

test03 = list(range(1,11))

total = test01+test02+test03

rd.sample(total, k = 5)
```

El resultado no permite averiguar de que lista procede cada dato:

```
[8, 10, 5, 3, 3]
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarse este problema?

Comment: ¿cómo querrías la salida? Se entiende el objetivo pero sería bueno indicar cómo exactamente querrías que fuera el resultado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En lugar de una lista con simplemente valores, usa una lista de tuplas. Cada tupla contiene un valor y la lista a la que pertenece:

```
test01 = [(x, 1) for x in range(1,11)]
test02 = [(x, 2) for x in range(11,22)]
test03 = [(x, 3) for x in range(22,33)]
```

Luego extraes la muestra como siempre:

```
total = test01+test02+test03

for pair in rd.sample(total, k = 5):
    print(f"Valor {pair[0]} de la lista {pair[1]}")
```

Produce:

```
Valor 10 de la lista 1
Valor 16 de la lista 2
Valor 12 de la lista 2
Valor 3 de la lista 1
Valor 23 de la lista 3
```